# Using XSLT in SandBox Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sandbox-solution

I need to fetch data from the list (which I am getting in XML) and then I need to apply the XML data to my XSLT so that it can produce HTML output.

I tried using SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath to get the XSLT which resides in 14 hive but SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath doesn't supported in Sandbox web parts.

I got that I will be uploading my XSLT somewhere into SharePoint Library, but the real question is How will I consume it?

SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath to get the XSLT isn't working in Sandbox.

How will I get the path of XSLT?

This is what I have done with Farm Web Part,  now I'm converting it into Sandbox  Web Part.

```
            //Transform XML To HTML using ContactList.XSLT
            XslCompiledTransform XMLTrnsfrm = new XslCompiledTransform();
            XMLTrnsfrm.Load(SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\ContactsXSLT.xslt"));
```

Any other solution in mind guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sandboxed solution you'll not be able to read from the file system so you need to put the XSLT file into a SharePoint document library then read it like this:

```
var file = web.GetFile(pathToXslt);
var bytes = file.OpenBinary();
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
var XMLTransfrm = new XslCompiledTransform();
XMLTransfrm.Load(reader);
```

Comment: When you say pathToXslt, you mean the full path to the xslt? like "http://mysharepointsite.com/sites/doclib/myxslt.xslt" ??

Comment: Also, file.OpenBinaryStream() is not working, OpenBinaryStream is throwing an error because It's not Available in Sandboxed Solutions.

Comment: It can be either the full path `http://mysharepointsite.com/sites/MySite/doclib/myxslt.xslt`, server relative `/sites/MySite/doclib/myxslt.xslt` or site relative `doclib/myxslt.xslt`

Comment: It's throwing Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Comment: What I did is just, XMLTrnsfrm.Load("http://mysharepointsite.com/sites/MySite/doclib/myxslt.xslt");

Comment: Sorry, I've changed to code to use OpenBinary instread (and tested it ;-)

Comment: reader is coming as None...not sure why....

Comment: In the debugger reader should say None as it hasn't read any node yet, but that OK

Comment: Right, but then I'm getting "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: str "

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry, I think I need to change my XSLT, let me try...thanks a lot :)  will mark as ans if it works!!